# Google Maps - event listener on markers created by Store Locator

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working from this example: http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html

I'd like to be able to add a listener to all markers like this, but I don't know how to reference them since they're created by the Store Locator from a DataFeed.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', //myCode);
```

This is the exact panel code from the example:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28, 135),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');

  var data = new MedicareDataSource;

  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
    geolocation: false,
    features: data.getFeatures()
  });

  new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not the best example modify. Have look at at Google's own [DEMO](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3).Although this uses a database it can be modified to use other data sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/custom.html) instead.  If all you want is to customize the infowindow content, just use that part.

```
// Store locator with customisations
// - custom marker
// - custom info window (using Info Bubble)
// - custom info window content (+ store hours)

var ICON = new google.maps.MarkerImage('medicare.png', null, null,
    new google.maps.Point(14, 13));

var SHADOW = new google.maps.MarkerImage('medicare-shadow.png', null, null,
    new google.maps.Point(14, 13));

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28, 135),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');

  var data = new MedicareDataSource;

  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
    geolocation: false,
    features: data.getFeatures()
  });

  view.createMarker = function(store) {
    var markerOptions = {
      position: store.getLocation(),
      icon: ICON,
      shadow: SHADOW,
      title: store.getDetails().title
    };
    return new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  }

  var infoBubble = new InfoBubble;
  view.getInfoWindow = function(store) {
    if (!store) {
      return infoBubble;
    }

    var details = store.getDetails();

    var html = ['<div class="store"><div class="title">', details.title,
      '</div><div class="address">', details.address, '</div>',
      '<div class="hours misc">', details.hours, '</div></div>'].join('');

    infoBubble.setContent($(html)[0]);
    return infoBubble;
  };

  new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
  });
});
```

**Or even do something like this:**

```
view.createMarker = function(store) {
  var markerOptions = {
    position: store.getLocation(),
    title: store.getDetails().title
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      alert("my code");
  });
  return marker;
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_store-locator_panelB.html)